# Too many arguments for method apply

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.2

I'm doing a little Play application in Scala and I receive this error when I want to open my app:

> too many arguments for method apply: (title: String)(content: play.twirl.api.Html)(implicit messages: play.api.i18n.Messages)play.twirl.api.HtmlFormat.Appendable in class main

I don't know what is wrong with my code, here is a quick view of my code:

main.scala.html:

```
@(title: String )(content: Html)(implicit messages: Messages)
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
          <head>
                <title>@title</title>
                <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/main.css")">
          </head>
```

Here the viewseleves.scala.html

```
@(eleves: Seq[Eleve])(implicit flash: Flash, messages: Messages)
@main(messages("title.eleves"), Some("viewEleves")){
  <div id="type_ead" class="list">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>@messages("institutions.list.institutions")</legend>
```

A screen of the error:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On this line:

```
@main(messages("title.eleves"), Some("viewEleves"))
```

you've passed two arguments to the main function created by your template, but it should only take one, a `String` called `title`.